# Can't select MKViewAnnotation twice?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I've got pins placed on a map and when I tap on them I'm calling the `didSelect`. The function only gets called the first time the pin is tapped, and after that it's not called on that same pin again unless I select another pin and then come back and tap it.

What that sounds like to me is the pin is being selected, and `didSelect` can only be called in unselected pins, so when I go tap on another pin it's deselecting the first pin and making it tappable again.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    view.isSelected = false
}
```

I don't understand why the above code does not work.

How can I allow my annotations be tapped more than one time in a row?

Comment: "I don't understand why the above code does not work." ... See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452381-setselected) that warns that one should not select/deselect the annotation views directly: "You should not call this method directly. An `MKMapView` object calls this method in response to user interactions with the annotation." Use `deselectAnnotation` on the annotation, and let the map view take care of the annotation views itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with this method `deselectAnnotation`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
     //do what you need here
     mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

There is another option, and that is to add a Gesture Recognizer for on the annotationView.
This will enable showing the `callout` view (since de-selecting the annotation immediately will not show it).

```
internal func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapPinTapGestureRecognizer)))
}

@objc private func mapPinTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Will get called on the second time the pin is selected.
    // And then, after that, it will be called every time.
}
```

Just don't forget to remove the recognizer when the annotation is no longer selected.

```
internal func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    // Remove the gesture recognizer when the annotation is no longer selected.
}
```

Comment: why the downvote? need some feedback to the answer so that it can be improved.

Comment: Solution is valid because the  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) can only be used one time. For deselecting this option is only valid